# how can I solve ldap socket closed error in spring LDAP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

I tried to make the sample program for my project. It is LDAP with spring boot.

I tested it in my development environment. Then, it works well. However, when I test it in the deployment environment, It occurs socket closed error.

The difference is just the LDAP URL and password(I couldn't make a password of admin with special characters, eg. @, #).

So, I tried to access LDAP using ldapsearch in deployment environment. Then, I got some errors. However, when I search for this error, I couldn't search a suitable solution for me.

This is my spring configuration for access to LDAP.

```
@Bean
public ContextSource contextSource() {
    LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();

    contextSource.setUrl("ldap://192.168.113.12");
    contextSource.setBase("dc=test,dc=test");
    contextSource.setUserDn("cn=admin,dc=test,dc=test");
    contextSource.setPassword("test2019!@");
    contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

    //for develop
//  contextSource.setUrl("ldap://192.168.0.192");
//  contextSource.setPassword("test2019");

    PoolingContextSource pcs = new PoolingContextSource();
    pcs.setDirContextValidator(new DefaultDirContextValidator());
    pcs.setContextSource(contextSource);

    TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy proxy = new TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy(pcs);

    return proxy;
}

@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
    return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
}
```

This is error pictures when access to LDAP using spring LDAP.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is error pictures using ldapsearch.

[image]
[image]

Help me.

ps. I didn't know how implemented the LDAP server, because it is installed by another team...

Answer (score 0):

I would say the port is missing ;)

```
contextSource.setUrl("ldap://192.168.113.12:389");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although there is no certain port in my spring code, in line 2 of the first error picture, the port number was set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Btw. in my opinion a nicer approach is to set the properties like this:

application.yml  (or application.properties)

```
ldap:
 contextSource:
 url: ldap://192.168.113.12:389 #Local
 base: dc=test,dc=test
 userDn: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=test
 password: test2019!@
```

and in the config class:

```
@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="ldap.context-source")
  public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
    return new LdapContextSource();
  }

 @Bean
 public ContextSource poolingLdapContextSource() {
   PoolingContextSource pcs = new PoolingContextSource();
   pcs.setDirContextValidator(new DefaultDirContextValidator());
   pcs.setContextSource(contextSource());

   TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy proxy = new TransactionAwareContextSourceProxy(pcs);

   return proxy;
  }
  // other configs like ldaptemplate
}
```